# What is the coefficient of x^9 y^16 in the expansion of (7x+21y)^25

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

`binomial(n, k) x^(n-k) y^k`

Given newtons binomial theorem.

I believe the answer is

n = 25
k = 16

`binomial(25, 16) 7^(9) 21^16`

Answer (score 2):

Yes true. By binomial theorem we have

$$(7x+21y)^{25}=\sum_{k=0}^{25}{25\choose k}(7x)^k(21y)^{25-k}$$
so for $k=9$ the term is
$${25\choose 9}7^9\times (21)^{16} x^9 y^{16}$$

Comment: It would be a little better to have the applicable $k$ be $16$ to match the original post.  As ${25 \choose 9}={25 \choose 16}$ the answer is OK